# Laravel 5 handle return from controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have an application that has many views that use need to inject some code into specific sections of the view. In a previous application I had used the root controller to do this and used special functions however it kind of changes the normal workflow of creating a laravel application to do it that way.

Basically say you have a create function

```
public function create()
{
   return view('something');
}
```

And you want to add something to a specific section, normally you would do this in the view and add any data needed to the call for the view. I want to do this in the controller but since any function returning a view would show the same thing in this case I want to simplify it a bit.

I tried looking but I could not find anything about post processing on a controller function, is there anything like that? Here is an example.

```
public function beforeRender($instance)
{
   if ($instance instanceof View)
   {
      $instance->getFactory()->inject('context-menu', $someData);
   }

   return $instance;
}
```

The beforeRender function would run after the create function in the controller and alter the return, allowing for a special return for anything with a view.

So my question is if there is anything like this in laravel 5 (or similar) and how I might do it. In a previous app I had remade how laravel handled controllers but I want to avoid doing that this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the feature is to be implemented in Laravel 5.1. You may grab dev version or wait until release is out.

[Service Injection](http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#service-injection) in Laravel docs:

```
@inject('metrics', 'App\Services\MetricsService')

<div>
    Monthly Revenue: {{ $metrics->monthlyRevenue() }}.
</div>
```

You may check [Code Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers) as well. The approach is a bit different, keeping views spick and span:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('count', $this->users->count());
}
```

Comment: I don't think its what I am looking for but it does get my mind working in different ways to think about it. I want to avoid adding the same blocks of code for sections that are the same for multiple controller functions.

Comment: You may check [Code Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers) as well. The approach is a bit different, keeping views spick and span.

Comment: Thank you! I can never thing of the right search terms for these things but that looks like its exactly what I am looking for, right down to using service providers to define them.